# Wordpress: jquery.js wont move to footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
function uw_load_scripts() {
// De-register the built in jQuery
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
// Register the CDN version
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js', array(),'','1.1', true); 
// Load it in your theme
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uw_load_scripts' );
```

I have this nice function in mytheme/function.php. They say this should move the js to the footer, but in my case it doesn't. Any idea on why or/and how to move it to footer?

Comment: Is there a `the_footer()` hook in the footer.php page? Wordpresses uses this to hook scripts on.

Comment: I have wp_footer(); before /body tag

Comment: `wp_footer()` inclides the file `footer.php` at that spot. Does that file contain the `the_footer()` hook?

Comment: @Broxzier `wp_footer()` fires the wp_footer action which prints scripts or data before the closing body tag on the front end. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HOW IT WORKS**

Here in your code `$in_footer` parameter of `wp_register_script()` is set to `true`.

You can enqueue in the footer by setting the `$in_footer` parameter to `true` in your call to `wp_enqueue_script()` or `wp_register_script()`

**[Reference>>](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)**

**WHY YOU CANT**

Your link towards jquery seems to be invalid. Use correct link.
You can use this one instead;

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

**AND**
Change version accordingly or set `false`,

Where version is,

**String specifying the script version number, if it has one, which
 is concatenated to the end of the path as a query string. If no version is
 specified or set to false, then WordPress automatically adds a version number
 equal to the current version of WordPress you are running. If set to null no
 version is added. This parameter is used to ensure that the correct version
 is sent to the client regardless of caching, and so should be included if a**

Comment: Thank you for this tip regarding to the version

Answer (score 0):

You can move it down by using true in your enque function but if the script you are enqueueing has anything defined as a dependency in WordPress’ wp_default_scripts() function, it will ignore your request to put it in the footer.

See Here

[Getting all JavaScript into the Footer in WordPress](http://blog.cloudfour.com/getting-all-javascript-into-the-footer-in-wordpress-not-so-fast-buster/)

Answer (score -1):

There is an typo "1.1.10" should be "1.10.1" otherwise you get an 404 Error.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: Yeah, vote me down. Maybe next time you look, that I can't comment with < 50!

Comment: Than wait until you can. This is just not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

**Try below code

```
function uw_load_scripts() {
// De-register the built in jQuery
wp_deregister_script('jquery');
// Register the CDN version
wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.1.10/jquery.min.js', array(),'','1.1', true); 
// Load it in your theme
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'uw_load_scripts' );
```

from function.php or comment it.
Now add your js to your theme/footer.php** 
Code :

```
      <script type="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I dont know who given down vote to me but its solution so just want to tell you see the solution not its way of represent.

Comment: The downvote is probably because adding jQuery in footer.php will lead to problems. Other scripts might depend on an enqueued (through `wp_enqueue()`) jQuery script. It may lead to double inclusion or errors because of script order.